# Choose number from element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I thought it will be simple, but wasn't. So, please, someone help me in following:
I need to pickup number from following html:

```
<ol class="competition-standings">
<li class="list-item row">
<div class="column large-4 competition-standings-user ellipsis">
<div class="column large-2 small-3 competition-standings-data">
<strong>1133</strong>Posted
```

To pickup 1133

Tried following:

```
Select tipsnumber = new Select(findElement(By.xpath("correct xpath")));
    tipsnumber.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
    System.out.println(tipsnumber);
```

And this also

```
WebElement tipsnumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("correct xpath"));
    tipsnumber.getAttribute("value");
    System.out.println(tipsnumber);
```

For both not getting number **1133**

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the value of "correct xpath"? Is tipsnumber null or are you getting an element in it?

Comment: @SakshiRaina Sorry, for confusion, I am getting actual xpath as result 
`div/ol[1]/li[3]/div[4]/strong` 
when printed in console 
While expected **1133**

Comment: Can you try : driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.column large-2 small-3 competition-standings-user ellipsis")).Text;

Comment: @SakshiRaina unfortunately same result - **getText** can only use, not just **Text**

Comment: why are you using select in first part, is it a drop down?

Comment: @SakshiRaina - It was correct your assistance, I just did wrong. Thank you it solved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you are choosing to use an Xpath selector?
Personally I would use a CSS type selector as below

```
WebElement tipsnumber = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Strong"));
System.out.println(tipsnumber.getText());

>>1133
```